# Modelling concurrent programs implemented using CSP

Tags: go, concurrency

Is there a recognised graphical modelling language for Communicating Sequential Processes?

I'm learning how to implement concurrent programs via CSP using Go. Before I write code I want to explore and model various patterns/designs.

======== EDIT ========

Have starting reading this http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf

Comment: Do we talk about [Communicating Sequential Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) or [Constraint Satisfaction Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Satisfaction_Problem) ? I would tend for the first, but who knows ?

Comment: Given the tags I'd say it pretty obvious (one of them is Communicating Sequential Processes) , but I'll edit the question to aid the unobservant.

Comment: Didin't looked at the tag... however, the edit should prove useful.

Comment: And I don't know of any standard graphical modeling language, even if I don't doubt that UML can do it.

Comment: Some UML to CSP related PDFs: http://www.ijcsi.org/papers/IJCSI-8-2-368-374.pdf , http://www.informatik.uni-marburg.de/~swt/agtive-contest/UML-to-CSP.pdf . The first link references the second, but there are a few more references in there as well, including http://www-i3.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/files/agtivetc/UML_to_CSP.pdf ("Using PROGRES for Transforming UML
Activity Diagrams into CSP Expressions
") *"In this paper, we describe how an UML activity diagram can be transformed into a corresponding CSP expression by using the graph rewriting language PROGRES"*

Answer (score 1):

A little bit off-topic but for my thesis I used a tool framework called [TERRA/LUNA](http://www.ce.utwente.nl/ECSSoftware/) which aims for software development for Embedded Control Systems but is used heavily for all sorts of software development at my institute.
I don't think there is a " recognised graphical modelling language" yet but
TERRA is a graphical CSP and software architecture editor so maybe it'll help checking how they implement CSP graphically.
In a nut-shell you've got Readers, Writers and Ports in order to use the CSP channels which connect the CSP processes and you can put them all in a relation to other processes like "parallel" or "sequential". 
A typical construct could look like this:
[image]

There is also [material](http://www.ce.utwente.nl/ECSSoftware/documentation.php) that documents the development of the framework and explains the motivation behind how the implementation was chosen for.

Comment: Hi Jim, I tried to use TERRA but I find it quite difficult to understand the errors generated by the validation. Is there some sort of documentation or tutorial on how to use the interface. The docs listed in the project web site are just the papers regarding the tool.

Also, if you have a link to your course or the materials, it would be nice because I am myself learning CSP

Comment: @user1125516 Sure, it's quite a lot of material though. You might want to have a quick look at the video material, recorded during the course, first. https://vimeo.com/search?q=%22Real-time+Software+Development%22+16-17 You'll find my contact details in my profile for more questions.